# 「誘います」は「招待します」とどう違いますか？

Tags: usage

What’s the difference between 誘いますand 招待します? Are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the same, but 招待　is more formal and is better for "abstract" invitations (I mean, if 誘う is good for "come here", 招待　can imply a more common "recommendation". Also if e.g. talking about some (elitistic) club accepting new members only based on invitations, 招待　would be the choice when referring to a member inviting someone to join).

In addition, 招待 is often used as a noun, in sentences like Xの招待で行きました）

Maybe an inappropriate and disputable example, but since it is Friday:

1) If A asks a friend/colleague B on "a few drinks" "飲みに行こうぜ" and they split the bill, then B will later explain his/her angry wife/husband/partner that Aに誘われました

2) If A asks B on a weekend trip to his 別荘　("cottage") then it is 招待